# wsdl2java goal in cxf-codegen-plugin does not notice changes in xsd

Tags: java, maven, xsd, wsdl, cxf-codegen-plugin

How can I make the cxf-codegen-plugin and wsdl2java goal check that the xsd files used by the wsdls have been modified? When I make a change in the xsd and then run `mvn verify` it doesn't recompile the jar file.

Snippet of the plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-us-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${schemas.location}/usidentityservice.wsdl
                        </wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-all</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-validate</extraarg>
                            <extraarg> -wsdlLocation
                            </extraarg>
                            <extraarg> classpath:/us.wsdl
                            </extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${schemas.location}/usv2.wsdl
                        </wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-all</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-validate</extraarg>
                            <extraarg> -wsdlLocation
                            </extraarg>
                            <extraarg> classpath:/usv2.wsdl
                            </extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

An unfavorable solution would be to put the [maven clean plugin](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/usage.html) so that it cleans each time and doesn't miss the xsd change but this will also clean it every time which makes the build slowed.

Comment: tried `mvn clean verify` ?

Comment: @mediahype `clean verify` works because it deletes the jar so it knows it has to remake it, what I am trying to figure out is why changing the xsd doesn't trigger a recompilation and how to make it do this, was I not clear enough? (Honest question, no sarcasm intended)

Comment: oh... other guess: the verify phase comes before generate-sources, to wich you have the cxf plugin bound. Maybe running `mvn generate-sources` helps ?

Comment: @mediahype thanks for the guess but according to the [default lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) `generate-sources` is the third phase and `verify` is the third from last (and there are more than 4 :P ).